# ResultSet Handling in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

I am working with MySQL and am writing a method, that takes a certain id (int) to search through a table to see if it exists. It then shall (if it exists) return the other Column entries, so that I have them returned as a String or int or double (depending on the column). I am using a resultSet that is being printed in the end, so that i can see if it has worked. But I only get this an output:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl@815b41f
and I have no Idea what I did wrong and how to solve this problem.

I am hoping someone can help me pls.

[[image: I added this picture but can only show a short part of my code due to data privacy. I also know some words are german but these are only Mitglieder (english = person) = name of my table and personalnummer = the column of a persons id1]

Answer (score -1):

I think i solved it now with a loop and getString(int)/(String) etc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).